# Optimal way to ensure C dependency is met in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dependencies

I'm writing a gem which depends upon `ffmpeg`, is there any way I can make ffmpeg install along with the gem, or create a command which installs ffmpeg without brew?

What is optimal in this situation and also prevents ffmpeg from being installed twice?

Comment: Looking for the exact thing..

Answer (score 0):

That kind of things should be written as rake tasks and the rake file should be included as part of the gem.

Comment: Can I make the rake task execute when the gem installs? That's what I need then.